# How can you see if your code is running in test mode with specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

How do you check if you program is being tested from inside the application with specs2? For example in Play you can check with `play.Play.isTest()`

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: Well for starters you want to use a different database when testing. There are other ways to achieve this (which I have done), but sometimes a simple solution is all that is needed. For example, I may want to add sensitive data to my log info, that I don't want users to be able to see in production by fiddling with the external logging config.

Comment: Making the code's behaviour dependent on whether it's running in test or production mode may be a simple solution in the short term... and may easily backfire in the long term.

Comment: I fully agree, thanks. But sometimes ham-handed approach is justified. In my case, using a cake pattern to achieve my objective led to complicating the system (difficult for other team members to understand) for little benefit, so I'm taking it out and revisiting the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper DI technique such as Cake (or even in simpler cases constructor parameter injection) and you have control over things that need to be done differently or take variant forms during testing.

Comment: Thanks, I realise that is the correct way to go (I used Cake earlier), but it can become a little tricky to maintain for more junior developers. I'm looking for a good, but simple way to achieve this.

Comment: It probably seems simpler to be able to write a little `if (testMode) ... else ...` where you need it, but that quickly becomes unmanageable. Better to take the hit in terms of climbing the learning curve once and for all and avoid the "technical debt" of the more comfortable but far less tractable approach. I recently went through this very process. This time 'round I used constructor injection, which to me felt more comfortable. Fortunately, the system is fairly simple and also has no long-term existence. But for the next big system I'm going with full cake.

Answer (score 0):

As a heuristic, depending on where you make that call, you can probably fill-in a stacktrace exception and check if a specs2 method gets executed.